# Change the ordering of UIActivityViewController items

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a few custom activityviewcontroller items (sample ordering, adding to favorites, custom emailing), as well as the default COPY and PRINT options.

Currently the ordering is shown as

```
Copy, Print, Order Samples, Add to Favorite, Email
```

I want to change it so that the Copy and Print are the last items. Is this possible?

Comment: This is inside an array ? Why don't just change the array's order ?

Comment: the copy and print options are not in the same array (they are default UIActivities for iOS). my array only contains the Order Samples, Add to Favorite, and Email functions

Comment: @kevinl could you find a solution? I am also facing a similar problem.

Comment: @Dinesh No i didn't find a solution.